# Clone row and maintain a reference to cloned row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to clone some row from a table, the row must be selected using a specific condition, but I also need to save in a temporary table N pair(sourceRowID, destinationRowID)

I've tried using `OUTPUT` but I can't use fields of the source row

```
INSERT INTO myTable(Value1, Value2)
OUTPUT myTable.ID, Inserted.ID 
INTO @tempTable(sourceRowID, destinationRowID)
SELECT Value1, Value2
FROM myTable
WHERE Value2 > 10
```

Is there a solution to this? Unfortunately I am constraint to use SQL server 2008

UPDATE: 
For now this is my solution:

First of all I write the inserted record using the `OUTPUT` instruction to the `@tempTable` ensuring that the records are inserted ordered by `ID`

At this point I've the `@tempTable` that contains, for example

```
sourceRowID | destinationRowID
-------------------------------
    NULL    |      12
    NULL    |      15
    NULL    |      16
    NULL    |      23
```

than I update `@tempTable` retrieving again the same record with the same `WHERE` condition joining the `@tempTable` and the retrieved record by RowNumber ensuring again that the records are retrieved ordered by `destinationRowID`, in this way the order of new and old record must be the same, and with the update I'll obtain the `@tempTable` with correct `sourceRowID` and `destinationRowID`

Comment: Have you considered using triggers to make a copy into a history table?  And then you can use OUTPUT to lookup those values from the history table?  If that sounds like something that could work for you I'll write up an example as an answer.

Comment: Yes, this is maybe a way, for now my approach is different, see my update in the answer